# What's the non-deprecated way to invoke Android's Contact List?

Tags: android, contactscontract, contact-list

This question hasn't been answered since they deprecated the `Contacts.People` type, and all the answers I could find still involve its use. How can it be done without using `People.NAME` and `People.NUMBER`?

In other words, I already know that you can start the Contact List with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

...and then you have to create a method called onActivityResult, which has to look like this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (reqCode) {
    case (1):
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            Cursor c = this.getContentResolver()    
                       .query(contactData,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                int contact_id = c.getInt(c
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.?????????));
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

...so, what non-deprecated column names should I expect to find in `Cursor c`? I can't find any updated documentation on this, and Google only returns examples with deprecated `People.NAME` and `People.NUMBER` columns.

The `ContactsContract` class is a Byzantine morass of... stuff, in which I can't find anything that looks like it has anything to do with `People.NAME` or `People.NUMBER`, so answers that say "just read the documentation for `ContactsContract`" are completely unhelpful.

Perhaps there is little point in editing this in after it's already been marked as [duplicate], since nobody will ever read it.

Worst of all, since I can't comment, I can't ask for clarification on other versions of this question. I have to ask a new question.

Comment: Have you seen the reference [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html)? I think it might be helpful.

Comment: Beyond that, feel free to explain, in detail, what "invoke Android's Contact List" means.

Comment: "invoke Android's Contact List" means that the phone presents the user with the Contact List, then after the user picks a contact from the list, this data is returned to my Activity's onActivityResult method. I can't figure out how to extract the data from the Intent object passed to that method because I have no idea what columns to expect in the Cursor that can eventually be extracted from the Intent object passed to onActivityResult..

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following link for more information
http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html

Comment: It certainly tells you how to do a lot of things with Contacts Provider, but it doesn't give me a clue as to what could serve as a drop-in replacement for example code on what to do with the data given to `onActivityResult`. I'll edit the question to make it more clear.